# MySQL: CROSS JOIN unexpected behavior

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, phpmyadmin

world!

Part from textbook on MySQL I read:

"Suppose you join two tables using `CROSS JOIN`. The result set will include all rows from both tables, where each row in the result set is the combination of the row in the first table with the row in the second table. This situation happens when you have no relationship between the joined tables."

So if I understand right the above means: if tables have relationship `CROSS JOIN` will not combine each row from `table_one` with each row from `table_two`.

But my testing tables have relationships (foreign keys).

`table_one` has user's data, `table_two` has orders data.

`user_id` from `table_two` is related to `id` from `table_one`

But `SELECT * FROM table_one CROSS JOIN table_two` continue to combine each rows from both tables. Why?

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation means that you would *normally* use `CROSS JOIN` when there is no relationship between the two table.

`CROSS JOIN` always produces the Cartesian products of the two tables/subqueries, regardless of whether or not there is a relationship.

Do note that if either table is empty, then the result set is also empty.